# How to get the foreignKey related primary key (pk) in the same model in django?

Tags: python, django, primary-key

I need to get the id (pk) of a related model.foreignKey object in order to set the "upload_to" attr of a model.FileField of the same model.

Something like this:

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(RelatedModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=str(related_model.id)+"/")
```

So for example, if the related_model has the primary_key 10 the upload_to attr has to be "10/"

It is possible or I have to set that value in the view.py file when the object is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) as the `upload_to` parameter.

```
def related_path(instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}'.format(instance.related_model_id, filename)

class myClass(models.Model):
    related_model = models.ForeignKey(RelatedModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=related_path)
```